# AWS SAM/AWS Toolkit Docker Mounting Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

What path do I add to docker to enable AWS SAM to locally debug? Adding the path to the directory in which I work normally does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: add this path to docker: `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode`

The directory that needs to be mounted is the directory that sam COMPILES TO, NOT the directory in which you normally work in e.g onedrive, documents.